# recalculating field from datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, linq, datagridview

I have a datagridview which is filled based on a calculation sum of another datagridview.
In my DGview I have 4 columns, a number (i++), the person's name, the hours, the minutes. Person's name is a group-by, hours is the sum of all hours of DGview1, minutes is the sum of all minutes from DGview1.

But it may occur that the sum of minutes results in e.g. 214. Is it possible to recalculate this into 2 other column where the sum of hours is added PLUS (214minutes) 3hours and then in another column the rest of minutes : 34?

Or even better recalculated/replaced into the original columns of DGview2, so without adding 2 more columns?

Comment: Do you create rows of DGview2 manually?

Comment: TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(grp.Minuut); TimeSpan intervalH = TimeSpan.FromHours(grp.Sum); interval = interval + intervalH; string timeInterval = interval.ToString(); Works, but how can I do a sum of all cells containing this timespan ? I found something like TimeSpan total = list.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (subtotal, t) => subtotal.Add(t)); But DGview does not have a .Aggregate :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [TimeSpan Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) to either calculate the sum all along, or use the TimeSpan.FromMinutes() method to create it from the minutes total.

Comment: TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(grp.Minuut);

TimeSpan intervalH = TimeSpan.FromHours(grp.Sum);

interval = interval + intervalH;

string timeInterval = interval.ToString();

Works, but how can I do a sum of all cells containing this timespan ?
I found something like TimeSpan total = list.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (subtotal, t) => subtotal.Add(t));
But DGview does not have a .Aggregate :(

Comment: I've never worked with DGView, so can't say for sure, but as long as it's a collection you can use the .OfType<T>() Method to convert it into a LINQ-supported Enumerable, and than do .Aggregate().